# fbconnect for iOs 5?

Tags: facebook, ios5

I am using iOs 5.and in my project i need to integrate facebook and i add facebook sdk for that but as we all know release is not needed in iOs 5 so it showing me error so i deleted all that release, autorelease,retain in all sdk still its not working...
is there any way to solve that issue..
     or an link where i can download latest sdk for Facebook integration ??

```
#import "FBConnectGlobal.h"

const NSString* kFB_SDK_VersionNumber = @"iphone/1.2.2";

const void* RetainNoOp(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value) { return value; }
void ReleaseNoOp(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value) { }

 NSMutableArray* FBCreateNonRetainingArray()
{
      CFArrayCallBacks callbacks = kCFTypeArrayCallBacks;
      callbacks.retain = RetainNoOp;
      callbacks.release = ReleaseNoOp;
      return (NSMutableArray*)CFArrayCreateMutable(nil, 0, &callbacks);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey chirag this is problem with fb sdk for ios 5. if you wants to integrate fb for sharing than You can use opensource sharekit for that. this is easy to implement and can integrate all the popular social networks.

This is working fine with ios 5 i have tested it. you can get it from following link.

http://www.getsharekit.com

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *FBCreateNonRetainingArray(void);
const void* RetainNoOp (CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value);
void ReleaseNoOp(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value);
```

just declare this function in FBConnectGlobal.h , All the warning will go .***